# Search for a specific number and stop the search once the number is found

Tags: sql, search, limit, sapb1

I am trying to create a short-cut identifier (as a column) within a query next to a lot of different and seemingly random item-code numbers within a table - I am working on SAP B1/HANA as I try to create these queries.

I want to search for a defined number between 0 - 39 inside each item-code. Once that number is found I need that search to stop, since a different number following later within the same item-code will mess up the process.

For example - for this item-code "`SS-810-3-8-6`" I would need my identifier to only show me an "`8`".

My query is not smart, though, and since I am using `CASE WHEN` statements that incorporates all those numbers one by one, the query is searching every item-code with the first `CASE WHEN` statement and ignores the following statements for the other numbers once it finds the first defined number.

The results returned are mostly 1 or 2, due to this.

Bad Example:

```
SELECT CASE  
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%1%' THEN '1' 
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%2%' THEN '2' 
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%3%' THEN '3' 
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%4%' THEN '4' 
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%5%' THEN '5' 
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%6%' THEN '6' 
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%7%' THEN '7'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%8%' THEN '8'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%9%' THEN '9'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%10%' THEN '10'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%11%' THEN '11'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%12%' THEN '12'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%13%' THEN '13'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%14%' THEN '14'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%15%' THEN '15'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%16%' THEN '16'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%17%' THEN '17'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%18%' THEN '18'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%19%' THEN '19'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%20%' THEN '20'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%21%' THEN '20'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%22%' THEN '20'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%23%' THEN '20'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%24%' THEN '20'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%25%' THEN '20'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%26%' THEN '20'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%27%' THEN '20'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%28%' THEN '20'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%29%' THEN '20'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%31%' THEN '30'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%32%' THEN '30'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%33%' THEN '30'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%34%' THEN '30'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%35%' THEN '30'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%36%' THEN '30'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%37%' THEN '30'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%38%' THEN '30'
WHEN T1."ItemCode" LIKE '%39%' THEN '30'

END AS "DOPPEL-CHECK"

FROM OITM T0
```

RESULTS IN:

```
DOPPEL-CHECK    ITEM-CODE
1               SS-810-3-8-6
6               MS-DMT-6M0
1               SS-6M0-R-12M
2               6LV-4-VCR-3-4TB2
4               SS-6-MTA-7-4
3               SS-43GXF4RT
1               SS-6M0-1-6RS
1               SS-6M0-1-6RS
2               SS-8-RSD-2V
1               SS-41GXS2
1               2507-1210-9-SG2
```

What I need:

```
DOPPEL-CHECK    ITEM-CODE
8               SS-810-3-8-6
6               MS-DMT-6M0
6               SS-6M0-R-12M
6               6LV-4-VCR-3-4TB2
6               SS-6-MTA-7-4
4               SS-43GXF4RT
6               SS-6M0-1-6RS
6               SS-6M0-1-6RS
8               SS-8-RSD-2V
4               SS-41GXS2
2               2507-1210-9-SG2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - please don't link to images, instead add all relevant information to your question as editable text. This allows someone to see all the information in one place and also allows them to copy your data if they want to try a solution

Comment: Hi - your case statement seems to suggest that you want to identify any number but given your logic, I can't see how you would ever get a number greater than 9. For example "SS-110-3-8-6" would always match 1, it would never match 11 or 110. If you are expecting numbers > 9 can you update your question with some examples and the logic being used?

Comment: Hi Nick. Thank you. Very true, I realized that, too. And since I am not aware of a better statement to figure out in order to "scan" every item for each defined number but also stop that scan once that defined number is found. Basically stop searching after the first occurance of "defined number". This was not achievable through my attempt. The problem is also that not every number can be found in the same spot, so I wasn't abel to solve this through maybe LEFT("item-code", X) or SUBSTRING().

Comment: Hi - you still haven't explained the business logic/rules (rather than the solution) for what you are trying to achieve. If a value contains the sequence of digits '11' (or 1-1 or 1GNJ1, etc) how to you determine if that should be treated as a '1' or an '11'?

Comment: Hi. Sorry. The items are physically sorted into boxes - labelled 1 to 39 - based on the first digit that is visually found on each item code. I need to mirror this process in a query to make it safer (linking it to a scanner once the query works). Having realized that these CASE WHEN statements will barely get passed the first defined numbers 1, 2, 3 etc. I couldn't think of something better. If digits like '11' or '22' occur they can still be treated as '1' or '2'. I can adjust the physical sorting process to those cases.

Comment: One (or both) of us seems to be having trouble communicating. How can you sort items into 39 different boxes based on the first digit when there are only 10 possible first digits (0-9)?

Comment: Hi Nick. Yes, I'm probably not following you due to my litte knowledge SQL. But... If I limit the CASE WHEN function to only one line looking for an '2507' item with the statement 'LIKE' '%2507%' I do get that item. But if a second CASE WHEN line precedes it with 'LIKE' '%2%' then the entire function never gets passed the '2'. So technically I can define a 39 and get it if I only use one CASE WHEN statment line. I realized that the system runs through each CASE WHEN line one by one and this will never work and I thought there may be a another function I'm not aware of. Thanks though.